# How to remove a ViewController after presenting another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I am working on an ARKit app (although ARKit doesn't matter here) with SceneKit (not SpriteKit, Metal or similar) and I would like to remove a ViewController after I have presented the next ViewController so that I can save resources.

So far I am just presenting "SecondVC" from "FirstVC" like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") 
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now I'd like to remove the ViewController from which I have presented the "SecondVC". I understand that I stack SecondVC on top of FirstVC. Is it somehow possible to remove or delete FirstVC completely?

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: No, I'm not using a UINavigationController.

Comment: Then probably not. It's usually not necessary to remove view controllers just to save resources, so if that really is your issue, and you have profiled your app and see a resource spike, then you should look at other ways of reducing the load. If not, and you just think that it's good practice, then I would suggest that it's not something you need to worry about.

Comment: How is `FirstVC` displayed?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use a UINavigationController but hide the navigationBar if you don't want it visible. Then you can set the viewControllers array to display whatever controllers you want.